# Webview vertical scrollbar cuts off the content

Tags: webview, uwp

I am using Webview in my UWP app to render some html content. The problem is, when the content is long enough to produce a scrollbar, the scrollbar would hide some of the content behind itself.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Actually I don't see a website content can be hidden by the scrollbar(I think websitee should not allow this).  Could you please provide a side that content can be hidden by scrollbar that I can do more testing on my side.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code ,that's how i fixed it.

```
this.webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { SetScrollbarScript });
    string SetScrollbarScript = @"
    function setScrollbar()
    {
        //document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';  
        document.body.style.msOverflowStyle='scrollbar';   
    } 
    setScrollbar();";`
```

Comment: you could either do that, or just add the CSS rule `body { -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar } ` on the target website if its within your reach